# Why I obtain this JavaScript error message into FireBug console when I click on this button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xhtml, dom-events

I am absolutely new in JavaScript and I have the following problem into a page that use it.

So I have a page in which I have this button:

```
<div class="bottoneDiv">

                <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                       value="Invia" onclick='Javascript: loadingPopUp(); return InviaEmail()'
                       onMouseOver="'Invia';return true"/>

                <input class="bottone" type="text" readonly
                       value="Indietro" onclick='Javascript: loadingPopUp(); return AnnullaEmail()'
                       onMouseOver="'Indietro';return true"/>
</div>
```

As you can see on this input button I have defined an `onclick` event so when the user click on the button it is performed the `loadingPopUp()` function that simply load a loading popup until the href page is loaded (it perfectly works in others page).

The problem is that in this page, when I click on the **Indietro** button in the FireBug console I have this error message:

> ReferenceError: Calendario is not defined
> VALORE_SOCIETA = 'CLIENTE PROVA';Calendario();

I can't understand why when I click this button it try to perform this `Calendario()` function (it seems to me that it is not called into the code of my `loadingPopUp()` function that simply is:

```
 function loadingPopUp() {

        var blurDiv = document.createElement("myPage");
        blurDiv.id = "blurDiv";
        blurDiv.style.cssText = "position:absolute; top:0; right:0; width:" + screen.width + "px; height:" + screen.height + "px; background-color: ci; opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=10)";

        try {
            // alert(navigator.appName);
            var is_ie = (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer");
            // alert(is_ie);

            if (is_ie) {
                top.window.workspace.document.appendChild(blurDiv);
            }
            // top.window.workspace.document.appendChild(blurDiv);

            top.window.workspace.document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';

        } catch (e) {
        }
        // document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';

    }
```

and the other called function simply redirect toward a specific URL:

```
function AnnullaEmail() {
    document.location.href = "edi.do?serv=4.0"
}
```

So, using the FireBug JavaScript debugger I can see that when I click on the **Indietro** button first is performed the previous `loadingPopUp()` function it seems to me that when perform this line an exception is thrown:

```
top.window.workspace.document.getElementById('light').style.display = 'block';
```

and after it in the FireBug console appear the error message:

> ReferenceError: Calendario is not defined
> VALORE_SOCIETA = 'CLIENTE PROVA';Calendario();

So I search in this page code this string and I found it:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td width="100%" align="RIGHT" valign="BOTTOM">
            <font size="-2" face="arial, helvetica">
                <script language="JavaScript">
                    VALORE_SOCIETA ='<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("USER")==null?"":((User)request.getSession().getAttribute("USER")).getRagioneSociale()%>';
                                Calendario();
                </script>
            </font>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This script session inside this table seems to be the cause of the error showed into the FireBug console when I click on the **Indietro** button because this message is generated from it but:

1. Why I obtain this error clicking on the **Indietro** button if it don't call this piece of code?
2. What is wrong with this piece of code? Why it generate this error message? How can I solve it?

Comment: Please check the onMouseOver eventListner Indietro

Comment: @KirenSiva "Indietro" seems to be only a String and not a JavaScript function.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the intention of this code. First, you say they're buttons, but they're textboxes. Second, what is `onmouseover="'Invia';"` supposed to do? And you can't create an element with tag name `myPage`. And what is `top.window.workspace`?